# Is CreateThread() a "synchronization point"?

Tags: winapi, thread-synchronization

I'm writing some Win32 code like this:

```
myctx.somedata = 42;
CreateThread(blablabla, &my_thread_entry_func, &myctx);
```

Can I expect the newly created thread to see the effect of `myctx.somedata = 42` as soon as it comes to life? And importantly, how could I have managed to look this up myself?

And while we're at it, how do things behave with `pthreads` under Linux?

Comment: It is, an OS can't get a thread added without a full memory barrier to protect its own internal data structures.  Those implicit barriers are very ugly, but everybody relies on it so they can never change it again.

Comment: @HansPassant, do you know the specific technical reason why the OS can't? Is each context switch a synchronization point?

Comment: yes, new thread of course will be see all memory writes happens-before `CreateThread` call. internally such cal do many interlocked writes to some variables, and new thread before start will be read from this variables too

Comment: It just isn't that different from the kind of code you write yourself.  It is a processor detail before it is a software detail, threads require locks or barriers to you as well as to the OS.

Answer (score 2):

internally with thread will be associated some structure, where os store thread data. this is for any os.

what is CreateThread (or any analog function) is doing ? it first create and initialize this structure and then push it in some internal scheduler database.

then scheduler (on arbitrary core) pop thread structure from this database and begin execute it code.

obvious than after scheduler pop thread data from database - it must view all data written to thread data before push. this mean that push must have how minimum release semantic and pop acquire semantic.

because `myctx.somedata = 42;` happens-before thread data is created, it of course also will be visible at point where thread data will be pop by scheduler. your user thread code will be executed after scheduler pop your thread data. so it of course will be view `myctx.somedata = 42;` too.